# Reverse for 'course_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'cd': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['courses/(?P<cd>\\d+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, cloud9

I am fairly new to Django and I followed a tutorial which helped create a blog using Django. That project went fine. But when I wanted to use what I learnt form that tutorial and make my own simple website that's when things went pear shaped. I have been at this problem for a long time now and it is really bugging me, so I hoped a fresh pair of eyes could help me decode the issue.

The error I am getting is this:

```
Reverse for 'course_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'cd': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['course/(?P<cd>\\d+)/$']
```

Now I know that in my original project I never had a "u'" before the 'cd' in my arguments and I have no idea where this is coming from, I have looked tirelessly for what is causing this and I can't find it.

Here is the rest of the code regarding this issue:

**course_list.html**

```
   {% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Courses</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/website.css' %}">
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="links">
                <h1><a href="">Home</a> |
                <a href="">Courses</a> |
                <a href="">Venues</a> |
                <a href="">About Us</a> |
                <a href="">Contact Us</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="page-header">
                <h1><a href="">Courses</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="content container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% for course in courses %}
                        <div class="course">
                            <h2><a href="{% url 'course_detail' cd=course.cd %}">{{ course.course_name }}</a></h2>
                            <p><b>Course code: </b> {{ course.course_code }}</p>
                            <p><b>Price: </b> {{ course.price }} </p>
                            <p><b>Course topic: </b> {{ course.topic_details }} </p>
                                <div class="date">
                                    <p><b>Start Date: </b> {{ course.start_date }}</p>
                                    <p><b>End Date: </b> {{ course.end_date }}</p>
                                </div>
                            <p><b>Availability: </b> {{ course.status }}</p>
                            <p><b>Course venue: </b> {{ course.venue }}</p>
                            <p><b>Room course will be held in: </b> {{ course.room }}</p>

                                <button class="button">Book Course</button>

                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <h3>Other Links</h3>
            </div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

**course_detail.html**

```
 {% extends 'website/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
                        <div class="course">
                            <p><b>Course code: </b> {{ course.course_code }}</p>
                            <p><b>Price: </b> {{ course.price }} </p>
                            <p><b>Course topic: </b> {{ course.topic_details }} </p>
                                <div class="date">
                                    <p><b>Start Date: </b> {{ course.start_date }}</p>
                                    <p><b>End Date: </b> {{ course.end_date }}</p>
                                </div>
                            <p><b>Availability: </b> {{ course.status }}</p>
                            <p><b>Course venue: </b> {{ course.venue }}</p>
                            <p><b>Room course will be held in: </b> {{ course.room }}</p>

                                <button class="button">Book Course</button>

                        </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Course

# Create your views here.
def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'website/course_list.html', {'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, cd):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, cd=cd)
    return render(request, 'website/course_detail.html', {'course': course})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list, name='course_list'),
    url(r'^course/(?P<cd>\d+)/$', views.course_detail, name='course_detail'),
]
```

**Full trace**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://yr4-group-project-mfblack.c9users.io/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'course_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'cd': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['course/(?P<cd>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/workspace',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Oct 2016 16:08:46 +0000
```

Hopefully someone can help as I have tried all the things I can think of to get it working. If there is need of any more code then please let me know.

**UPDATE:**
**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
        ('Fully Booked', 'Fully Booked'),
    )
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='add price')
    topic_details = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField('start date')
    end_date = models.DateField('end date')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MY_CHOICES)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
```

I tried your answer and it worked, I am getting the website loading now but now that I click on the a course name I get this error:

```
FieldError at /course/1/
Cannot resolve keyword 'cd' into field. Choices are: course_code, course_name, end_date, id, price, room, start_date, status, student, topic_details, venue, venue_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://yr4-group-project-mfblack.c9users.io/course/1/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'cd' into field. Choices are: course_code, course_name, end_date, id, price, room, start_date, status, student, topic_details, venue, venue_id
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1330
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/workspace',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Oct 2016 17:14:37 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace log is telling you that it cannot find a `course_detail` url with a blank captured group `cd`. (N.B. The `u` refers to unicode and has nothing to do with your issue.)

Your `course_detail` url expects one or more digits for `cd`:

```
r'^course/(?P<cd>\d+)/$'
```

But it is passed...nothing!

```
'course_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'cd': ''}'
```

Why? Because in your view, `{% url 'course_detail' cd=course.cd %}`, `course.cd` is blank.

I would need to see your `Course` model, but my suspicion is that you are simple using `cd` instead of the standard `id`. Try switching to `course.id`: that should fix the issue.

UPDATE:

Your second error is caused by the exact same issue in `views.py`:

```
get_object_or_404(Course, cd=cd)
```

`cd` here is undefined: you should change it to `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and thanks for helping me! I tried what you suggested and it works but now I get a different error, I have updated my original post with the new error.

Comment: So instead of get_object_or_404(Course, cd=cd) I should change it to get_object_or_404(Course, cd=course.id)?

Comment: I've also added my course model to my original answer if that helps.

Comment: Nope, other way around: `id=cd`